# Jfrog artifactory CI/CD integration with Azure - Artifact version control

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration, artifactory

I am using ArtifactoryGenericDownload@3 task to download .whl file from JFrog artifactory. However I want to only download the latest version which is python/de-cf-dnalib/0.7.0 but this cannot be hardcoded because the version needs to be updated from time to time. Could you please suggest any solution on how to add version control to my code ?

- task:

```
ArtifactoryGenericDownload@3
    inputs:
      connection: "JFROG"
      specSource: "taskConfiguration"
      fileSpec: |
        {
          "files": [
            {
              "pattern": "python/*.whl",
              "target": "./$(Pipeline.Workspace)/de-cf-dnalib"
            }
          ]
        }
      failNoOp: true
```

result:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "python/de-cf-dnalib/*.whl",
      "target": ".//datadisk/agents-home/...work/744/de-cf-dnalib"
    }
  ]
}
Executing JFrog CLI Command: /datadisk/hostedtoolcache/jfrog/1.53.2/x64/jfrog rt dl --url="https://jfrog.io/artifactory" --access-token=*** --spec="/datadisk/agents-home/agent-0/azl-da-d-02-0/_work/744/s/downloadSpec1656914680005.json" --fail-no-op=true --dry-run=false --insecure-tls=false --threads=3 --retries=3 --validate-symlinks=false --split-count=3 --min-split=5120

[Info] Searching items to download...

[Info] [Thread 2] Downloading python/de-cf-dnalib/0.5.0/de_cf_dnalib-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl

[Info] [Thread 1] Downloading python/de-cf-dnalib/0.6.0/de_cf_dnalib-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl

[Info] [Thread 0] Downloading python/de-cf-dnalib/0.7.0.dev0/de_cf_dnalib-0.7.0.dev0-py3-none-any.whl

[Info] [Thread 2] Downloading python/de-cf-dnalib/0.7.0/de_cf_dnalib-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl

{
  "status": "success",
  "totals": {
    "success": 4,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
```

[Artifactory from Jfrog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKfl4.png)

Answer (score -1):

fileSpec also supports filtering by Artifactory Query Language (AQL) instead of pattern.
With AQL, you can sort by version of create date, and get only the latest recorded file, for example:

```
items.find({
  "repo": "my-repo",
  "name": {"$match":"*.jar"}
}).include("name","created").sort({"$desc": ["created"]}).limit(2)
```

You can read more about AQL in the following link:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language